# Cluster two object arrays using months

Tags: javascript

I have two sets of arrays, one containing date values in months(in no order) the other containing corresponding month values as such;

```
array1=['jan','mar','dec','jan','sep','nov','mar']
array2=[3,5,5,4,5,8,2]
```

as seen, each month can appear more than once.

id like to cluster/sort this data to have 2 arrays that show month and corresponding total values, in essence, get all the values that correspond to january, sum them and output them to another array as well as a forth array containing months, without repeats. something like

```
array3=['jan','mar','sep',nov','dec']
array4=[7,7,5,5,8] //totals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a dictionary to keep track of identical months. If months repeated it will add to the value in dictionary.

```
array1=['jan','mar','dec','jan','sep','nov','mar']
array2=[3,5,5,4,5,8,2]

res = {}

for(let i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    if(array1[i] in res){
        res[array1[i]]+= array2[i]
    } else {
        res[array1[i]] = array2[i]
    }
}

array3 = []
array4 = []

for(let i in res){
  array3.push(i)
  array4.push(res[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use new Map() here and then just map to pick necessary values.

```js
array1=['jan','mar','dec','jan','sep','nov','mar']
array2=[3,5,5,4,5,8,2]

const months = new Map();
array1.forEach((month, index) => {
  months.set(month, (months.get(month) || 0) + array2[index]);
});

const array3 = Array.from(months, ([month]) => month);

const array4 = Array.from(months, ([month, summ]) => summ);

console.log(array3);
console.log(array4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach can also sort based on month number.

```js
let array1=['jan','mar','dec','jan','sep','nov','mar']
let array2=[3,5,5,4,5,8,2]

//this is for saving the index and final sorting after monthwise summing up values
monthsObj  = {};
['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'].forEach((name,index) => {monthsObj[name]=index})

function getSum(a1, a2){
   let obj = {};
   for(let i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
       //if the month is not present in the obj
     if(obj[a1[i]] === undefined) obj[a1[i]] = a2[i];
     else obj[a1[i]] += a2[i]; //otherwise add to the previous month value
   }
   //sort based on month numbers
   let sorted = [...Object.entries(obj)].sort(function(a, b) {
        return monthsObj[a[0]]-monthsObj[b[0]];
    });
   
   let final1 = [], final2=[];
   for(let i=0;i<sorted.length;i++){
       final1.push(sorted[i][0]);
       final2.push(sorted[i][1]);
   }
   
   console.log(final1, final2);
}

getSum(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references. With that, you can omit duplicate values in your array. (you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) resource for more information about `Set`.)

The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop. (The only difference is that a `for...in` loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.) for more details, you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
array1=['jan','mar','dec','jan','sep','nov','mar']
array2=[3,5,5,4,5,8,2]

const months = {};

array1.forEach((month, index) => {
  months[month]=(months[month] || 0) + array2[index];
});

const array3 = Array.from(new Set(array1));
const array4 = Object.values(months) ;

console.log(array3);
console.log(array4);
```